# Can't connect to Ubuntu 12.04 Microsoft Azure Instance

Tags: azure

I've created a Ubuntu 12.04 virtual machine in Microsoft Windows Azure and set a password. When I use my SSH client to connect to it, I enter the password but the server refuses it and says I'm entering the wrong password. Anyone else experience this problem? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you setup all necessary endpoints? http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/setup-endpoints/

Answer (score 2):

just make sure about a couple of points which I listed below,

1. you write your username correct when you connect to your
   server, its usually "azureuser" by default
2. you type in your dns or your global ip correctly
3. that the status of your virtual machine is "running"
4. your ssh command looks like this "ssh -p 22
   username@dns.cloudapp.net" , note this command is used when u don't
   have public key set, but if you do have public key, use this "ssh -p
   22 -i key.key username@dns.cloudapp.net" , since you said in your
   question , you only set password, then the first ssh command is the
   one you should use